# Get list of first keys from Dictionary[key1,key2] with tuple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, set

How can I get a list of all the (unique) values of the first keys from a double key dictionary?

Is iterating the key values and then applying np.unique() the only way?

```
key1=[]
for key in my_dictionary.keys():
    key1.append(key[0])

np.unique(key1)
```

Comment: What is a double key dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
key1 = set([key[0] for key in my_dictionary])
```

As @Aran-Fey suggested you could also use a set comprehension:

```
key1 = {key[0] for key in my_dictionary}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have a dictionary with tuple keys:

```
d = {('a', 'b'): 1, ('b', 'c'): 2, ('a', 'd'): 3, ('b', 'e'): 4}
```

You can extract a set of the first elements from your tuple keys using `set` with `map` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = set(map(itemgetter(0), d))  # {'a', 'b'}
```

The NumPy library and `numpy.unique` is only recommended for use with NumPy arrays or Python objects which can be efficiently converted to NumPy arrays, such as a list of numbers.